# Aligning UL Bullets Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="text-center" style="list-style-position: inside; vertical-align: middle;">
      <li>1234</li>
      <li>123456789123</li>
      <li>123456789123</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The output:

[image: List Output]

How do I get the bullet points to align even if the `li` elements aren't the same length, but keep the list centered?

Here is a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/kGjcy0YClw).

Comment: You added text-center and it looks centered. Are you trying to keep the bullets left and center *only* the text, independent of the bullets? (Which would look pretty weird.)

Comment: @DaveNewton I've edited my question, I have taken the `text-center` class off but would like to keep the list centered. [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/j7lP2sbU4i)

Comment: Centered in the div in which it's contained?

Comment: @DaveNewton correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the UL inline-block like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <ul class="text-left" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">
        <li>1234</li>
        <li>123456789123</li>
        <li>123456789123</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/XFzwCr74vu

Comment: Ahh that did it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply remove the class text-center.

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/G2wWpben77)

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul style="list-style-position: inside; vertical-align: middle;">
      <li>1234</li>
      <li>123456789123</li>
      <li>123456789123</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was unclear, but I need the list to be centered on the page

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap offset class

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
    <ul style="list-style-position: inside; vertical-align: middle;">
      <li>1234</li>
      <li>123456789123</li>
      <li>123456789123</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/kJZrkcx0k9)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-5">
    <ul class="text-center" style="list-style-position: inside; vertical-align: middle;text-align:left">
      <li>1234</li>
      <li>123456789123</li>
      <li>123456789123</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```